# Where to get copy of Android Studio's WiFiDirectDemo code?

Tags: android, android-studio, sample

Where can I get a copy of Android Studio's WiFiDirectDemo source code? I see lots of tech articles with broken links to http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/index.html. Much of Android documentation (such as http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/package-summary.html) also have this broken link. I have downloaded the latest Android Studio and the SDK Manager, and I cannot find any sample/demo code within the SDK's installation directory nor the Android Studio's installation directory. A 'Net search for "WiFiDirectDemo" isn't finding much either. Has this sample code been pulled for some reason?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo, presumably.

Comment: Thank you - I wasn't aware of that resource.

Answer (score 0):

They changed the project name to the "Beam Large Files". This project is not using Wifi p2p.
[Screenshot for Sample Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQTh8.png)